# Redirecting after login for specific roles

Tags: 7, users

I want to redirect specific users after a succesful login but I can't make it work. 
Here's my code:

```
function concessionaire_login_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
foreach ($account->roles as $role){
    if($role == "administrator"){   
    } else if ($role=="concessionnaire"){
        global $language;
        unset($_REQUEST['destination']);
        unset($_REQUEST['edit']['destination']);
        $url = "http://www.my-site.com/myfile.php";
        $options = array(
        'query' => 'id_rub=14&lg='.$language->language
        );
        drupal_goto($url,$options)

    }
}
```

}

I tried also with `header('location: $url')`, but it doesn't work either. Login_destination module was my first guess but I can't use variables..

Also is it possible to redirect to an external URL and passing POST parameters at the same time ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to look at:

'query' itself needs to be an array, not a string, eg...

```
array('id_rub' => '14', 'lg' => $language->language)
```

and if you want to call header() directly, you need some more parameters:

```
header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE, $http_response_code);
drupal_exit($url);
```

(and an exit for good measure...btw, that's all drupal_goto() is really doing anyway)

Comment: Oh and if you use the header() approach, which might not be considered best practice, $url is the full string, eg "h t t p://www.my-site.com/whatever?whatever", but I'd work on getting drupal_goto() working first.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it working calling header() instead of drupal_goto(), I still don't understand what's wrong with drupal_goto().

Comment: quite welcome.  take a look at drupal_goto() when you do get a chance though. it's in includes/common.inc and is barely 10 lines of code, so what you weren't/aren't doing is pretty simple :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out.

function login_user_login(&$edit, $account) {

```
 $urlAdministrator = 'yoururl';
```

$urlconcessionnaire = 'yoururl'

if (in_array('administrator', $account->roles)) {
    drupal_goto( $urlAdministrator );
  }
  if (in_array('concessionnaire', $account->roles)) {
    drupal_goto( $urlconcessionnaire );
  }
}

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module.

Comment: Doesn't the OP say that they've already tried that and it didn't fulfil their needs?